# cmake working for root not for other user

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I have a dummy compilation running in a buildbot slave.
When running with buildbot user I get:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/gcc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
...
cc1: error: /usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu: Permission denied
```

/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu does not exist but If I manually run it as su I get:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
```

and so on, I can later make and run generated executable
I'm assuming is not related to project file permissions because all files belong to buildbot user

Command running is just cmake .
OS is ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS server edition

Thanks

Comment: What are the permissions of /usr/local/include, and who owns it?

Comment: drwx------ 3 root   root   4096 May  9 08:45 include

Comment: Ok, adding read and execution permissions to /usr/local/include fixed the issue thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When CMake checks if `gcc` works, it creates a temporary file and tries to compile it.  In my experience this was always done in the local `CMakeFiles` files directory. It looks like for some reason it is trying to do this in `/usr/local/include` (It at least is trying to do *something* in that folder, hence the `cc1: error: /usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu: Permission denied`).

The issue is that as you indicated **only** root has access to read *or* write in that folder.  This seems a bit odd to me, because other should at least be allowed to read there.  Anyway, your buildbot does not have access there, and so the configuration fails.

You have three options.

1. Dig into what CMake is doing when it tries to access this file, and change it to do what it is doing in a location you own.
2. Change the permissions of `/usr/local/include` to so that everyone can write to `/usr/local/include`
3. Create a new group that buildbot belongs to, and change the group ownership of `/usr/local/include` to that.  Make sure you change permissions to 770.

Personally, I would try to do the first, because I would prefer CMake do do things local, not in the bowels of my system.  There are some log files in the `CMakeFiles` directory you can poke around in.